# spring batch multiple sources in multiple subdirectory

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-batch

I am new to spring batch and going though spring batch and read multipartItemReder , I guess multipartItemReader is not fit for my project . Please through your thoughts and guild be by giving few points .

I have more then 50 million xml files , like the below directory structure .

```
 GOOD
    0
      001/en/1.xml
      001/jp/1.xml
      002/en/2.xml
      003/en/3.xml
      004/jp/4.xml
       .... 
       ....
      999/jp/1.xml  
    1000
      001/en/1.xml
      001/jp/1.xml
      002/en/2.xml
      003/en/3.xml
      004/jp/4.xml
       .... 
       ....
      999/jp/1.xml  
    2000
    3000
    ... 
    .. no limit 
 REMAKE/
    0
      001/en/1.xml
      001/jp/1.xml
      002/en/2.xml
      003/en/3.xml
      004/jp/4.xml
       .... 
       ....
      999/jp/1.xml  
 PROCLAIMED/
 ...
  ...
  ....
  like 100 directories ..
```

each source(GOOD,REMAKE, PROCLAIMED ... etc)  has different  xml file formate .
1.I need to create Item processor for each  source . 
2.Each source will be a thread or with commit transaction=1 or thread span based on the number of lang files inside SOURCE////.xml , What is the better option . 
3.I still feel IteamReader is complex implementation. Here each xml file has one record only. please share your comments .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best pratice for this kind of scenario is to use
[partitioning](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html#partitioning); I haven't tried it so I can't help a lot, but I think partitioning is helpful when you have the same type data to manage and not in your case where data is a mix.

Now my 2 cents...
I'll go for [parallel steps](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html#scalabilityParallelSteps)

1. Each source managed as a separated thread using `split/flow`
2. No need to have `commit-interval` equals 1; you can use a large value (or a custom `CompletionPolicy` if you want a fine grained commit) to improve performance
3. Use a `MultiResourceItemReader` delegating to a `StaxEventItemReader` specific for every kind of source
4. Specialized processor for every kind of object returned by reader
5. Writer (depends of your needs)

---

```
<job id="job1">
  <split id="split1" task-executor="taskExecutor" next="lastStep">
    <flow>
      <step id="GOOD" />
    </flow>
    <flow>
      <step id="REMAKE" />
    </flow>
    <flow>
      <step id="PROCLAIMED" />
    </flow>
  </split>
  <step id="GOOD">
    <tasklet>
      <batch commit-interval="100">
        // Set MultiResourceItemReader and delegate to specialized StaxEventItemReader for GOOD file structure
        // Set specialized processor for GOOD object
        // Set writer (IDK which type)
      </batch>
  </step>
</job>
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.Really helped a lot ..I have one doubt on multiResourceItemReader . let say I have 30,000 files in GOOD/0 only , if good has  GOOD/0,GOOD/1000,Good/2000 total files will be  3*30,000. Do I need to further split GOOD step to 0,1000,2000 .. if yes the problum is .. 0,1000,2000 are not contents .. there might be only 0 under REMAKE .. or multiresourceIteamReader works will for >90,000 records . please suggest ..

Comment: No need to manually split because the "split" is automagically done by SB based on your commit-interval, of course wider commit-interval requires more memory to work (setting a balanced commit interval can improve performance drastically)